# Ghost/Phantom Workbooks/sheets appear in VBA Project list alongside legitimate sheets

Tags: excel, vba

[image: List of legitimate sheets and Phantom WorkSheets/Workbooks]

**(edited a day later - see end)**

Not sure what's happening here but it's occurring in a few workbooks I'm working with. Over time additional "Phantom" worksheets (or workbooks) appear as shown in the picture. Sheet13, Sheet14, Sheet15 etc are Phantoms and I have no idea how to get rid of them.

What I've tried so far:

1) Searching Google/Stackoverflow no joy but could be a terminology problem

2) Created SUBS to loop through ALL worksheets and workbooks but the only things it finds are the single workbook and the legitimate worksheets.

3) Creating code within one of the phantoms, which is possible. I created a simple SUB on workbook open within Sheet13 to return the name of the sheet or workbook, but no matter what code is there I get

```
Run Time Error '429':
ActiveX component can't create object
```

4) Changing properties on the phantoms. The properties for each phantom exactly mirror each other and mirror ThisWorkbook. If I make a change to one, say KeepChangeHistory to False, this is mirrored in ALL phantoms and ThisWorkbook. If I make the change back to True in another phantom, again ALL phantoms and ThisWorkbook are updated.

5) Checked links (greyed out). Tried F5 -> special -> objects "No Objects found".

I've basically tried everything I can think of and searched the internet over the past week before posting this here, as a last resort.

Does anyone have ANY idea what could be causing this (I'm leaning towards some bad object handling somewhere), but also HOW to remove them completely so the only things listed are the actual, real, worksheets?

Thanks for reading.

**edit**

It affects more than just this workbook (it's happening in 3 different workbooks), it is also getting worse over time. I have saved archived versions of all workbooks. If I go back a month, there are 2 "phantoms", if I go back 2 weeks there are 8 "phantoms" and if I look at one from just last week there are 13 "phantoms". This is one of the reasons I'm assume some poor object handling, likely related to ThisWorkbook is going on. Anyway, I'm going to take Rory's advice and create a new Workbook with NO phantoms and try and figure it out from there. Just want to thank Rory and Mark for taking the time to respond with ideas, it is appreciated.

Comment: Do you still see these objects if you launch excel in safe mode (hold down the ctrl key while starting normally) and reopen the file(s)?

Comment: Hi Rory - yes I still see them. I launched Excel in Safe Mode then opened the workbook and sadly, the same phantoms are there.

Comment: Then it sounds like workbook corruption to me. You could try simply copying all the real sheets to a new workbook?

Comment: Presumably only affecting one workbook. Check for any missing references. If workbook has any unique add-ins, disable them. I also searched MSDN Knowledge Base for "Excel VBA IDE" but there was nothing specific to your problem although there were posts about projects persisting in IDE after workbooks are closed. I did stumble on [http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/CodeCleaner.htm](http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/CodeCleaner.htm) which may help. Have you tried using the Open & Repair option on the workbook?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess the simplest answers are the best. What I didn't mention in the question is that each workbook I've worked on that has this problem is uploaded to a 3rd party application, which is, in turn, sent to a second 3rd party application (bespoke apps written by others).

The second application creates 1 or 2 of these "phantoms". I choose to work slightly differently to other developers and I actually use the output from the second application to make changes/fixes, then format that workbook and reupload to application one.

Over time, more and more "phantoms" appear, 1 or 2 per run through this process.

In the end, absolutely nothing to do with Excel, poor code (at least mine!), badly handled objects or anything else.

Thanks again to Rory and Mark for attempting to help. Maybe next time I'll actually start with the mindset of "I'm sure this ISN'T my fault!" and go from there!

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. I was reaching the Sheet41111. I used the option Book Inspection in the Information Menu, then I selected remove hidden objects and it luckily worked. 
See the image attached, my excel is in Spanish so maybe the option is not really called "Book inspection" in the English version.

Hope it is useful

Pd- Unhide the legitimate sheets because it will delete all hidden sheets. I suggest trying it in a copy of the book. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VE7B0.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uH56i.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have had the same issue. Don’t know the cause, but may be a crash and recover. Can’t confirm. Here is how to fix.

Make a spare copy of the spreadsheet and open it.
Create a new tab and move it to the far left.
Unhide all sheets.
Create a new speadsheet.
In the VBA project manager drag each module and forms to the new spreadsheet.
On the copy spreadsheet, highlight all tabs except the new one.
Right click and select MOVE, and move to new spreadsheet.
Delete the sheet1 and save new speadsheet and close the copy sheadsheet.
Test it.
You have moved all the good sheets and left the unwanted ones behind. If you have code in the Workbook object you need to copy that code over too. Need to keep one tab otherwise a blank spreadsheet will close when all sheets are removed.